# TypeScript type for the fetchMore

Tags: typescript, graphql, react-apollo

GraphQL has `fetchMore` method to fetch more data when needed.

Function itselt looks like below (src: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/)

```
fetchMore({
  variables: {
    offset: 10,
    limit: 10
  },
});
```

When you pass `fetchMore` function as a prop to child component, you have to define it's type in child component. I couldn't figure out what it should be. I used `any` but I would like to correctly typecast it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Typescript has function types like this.
`(x: number, y: number) => number`
Is it possible to write your own type here? Or will you need something more complicated?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Please edit your question and add some code examples of what you are talking about. And you're likely to get even more help if you can create minimal example of the problem on a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and paste the link to that in your question as well.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#fetchmore  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/

Comment: @nlta yes, something like that but not able to come up with the exact definition. Whatever I tries, rest of the code starts throwing error

Comment: @Alex Wayne  Edited my question. Hopefully, that should be able to provide more context on what am I looking for

Comment: @xadm Thank you. Looking in to the link you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nlta based on your suggestion, this is what I did. Hopefully, it will help someone

```
export type FetchMoreArgs = {
  offset: number;
  limit: number;
};

fetchMore: ({ variables: FetchMoreArgs }) => void;
```

Comment: Actually I had TS error doing this, but:
fetchMore: (params: { variables: { FetchMoreArgs } }) => void;
worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of fetchMore from apollo and pass the two types of your query into your componet props.

```
export interface ChildComponentProps<TData = YourGetQuery, TVariables = YourGetQueryVariables>{
  fetchMore<TFetchData = TData, TFetchVars = TVariables>(
    fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<TFetchVars, TFetchData> & {
      updateQuery?: (
        previousQueryResult: TData,
        options: {
          fetchMoreResult: TFetchData;
          variables: TFetchVars;
        }
      ) => TData;
    }
  ): Promise<ApolloQueryResult<TFetchData>>;
}
```

Similarly, you can create for refetch as well.